# Android persistent music control bar like in Google Play Music

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

Currently I have a ViewPager with four different tabs in my app. I am looking to add a small bar at the bottom that displays music controls, but I need it to persist when swiping between tabs. The ideal functionality is in something like Google Play Music where the pull up panel stays at the bottom when swiping between the different tabs. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

[AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) is exactly what you need, it's open sourced by Umano so you can check out [their app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sothree.umano) to see how it works.

**Edit:**

A quick test with the code below provides the desired result - the bottom bar doesn't "slide" along with the tab change:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom">
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="142dp"
    android:background="#CFCFCF">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TEST"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have clarified. I'm already using Umano's panel, I just can't figure out how to keep the bar at the bottom of the screen between each tab in the VewPager. Currently, when I swipe to a new tab I get a new instance of the Panel, whereas I just want one Panel that persists across each tab.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you have your ViewPager, but you can have the SlidingUpPanelLayout in the ViewPager's container layout.

For example, if you have a ViewPager in an activity, you can have the SlidingUpPanelLayout as a parent in the activity's layout.